# How do mangaka draw the white lines in a black and white manga?

Tags: manga-production

How do mangaka draw those white lines which are used to distinguish folds and other indications in the black and white manga?

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't really know what you mean from the textr

Comment: I'm assuming he means like this: http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kyfcm0WHQj1qamhyd.jpg, where Sasuke's pants have white lines, defining the folds.

Comment: It only makes sense to use a white pen/pencil/brush tool or an eraser tool to do it

Comment: @Alex-sama yeah thats the one . So thatsall? Just an eraser tool ? Lol

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of making white spaces when drawing; it's either by not inking that part, or plainly drawing with white-out. I don't know about the modern manga-kas but the ones working in traditional media use a fountain pen-type to ink. Though the fountain-pen they use normally don't have the ink inside it as the fountain-pens you can buy in normal stores; they have the drawing head and you dip it in ink, or in wite-out if that's the desired effect.

In practice, the white-out is acting like white ink.